# How do you reference a file in a path that has a space in it in Java?

Tags: java, io, filepath

I'm working on a project that involves reading a txt file, and the way I currently have it set up is with...

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(url)));
```

...where url is a String. I don't have it set up for the user to input their own file path (or my ultimate goal to be able to choose it in a window, but that's a different matter), so I Just have url set to something like...

```
"file:///C:/Users/Jeremiah/Desktop/generic_text_file.txt"
```

My problem is that, with this technique, I can't include spaces in the file path or I'll get an invalid character exception, yet most of files and directories on a computer that a person actually deals with has spaces in it, even ones that come on the computer like "My Documents".

I've also tried passing the String through a method to escape the spaces by adding "\" in front of them, but that still isn't working.

```
public String escapeSpaces(String string){
    int cursor = 0;
    System.out.println(string);
    while(cursor<string.length()){
        if(string.charAt(cursor)==' '){
            string = string.substring(0,cursor)+"\\"+string.substring(cursor, string.length());
            System.out.println(string);
            cursor++;
        }
        cursor++;
    }
    return string;
}
```

So how would one get around this issue so that I could instead reference a file in say...

```
"file:///C:/Users/Jeremiah/Desktop/S O M A N Y S P A C E S/generic_text_file.txt"
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: If you know it's a file, why are you routing it through a URL instead of just using it directly?

Comment: @chrylis: Could be any number of reasons - maybe the real code takes a generic URI and then infers its a file from the scheme.

Comment: Well if it's the case that you don't need to use URLs (which I suspect), then I think it'll work. I believe you can pass in a string with spaces into the `File` constructor.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth In which case still there's no point to the little dance.

Comment: OP: You are wanting to play with a *URL*. Did you properly encode it?

Comment: I tried removing the URL bit and just put the url String in the File constructor. While I don't think that really changes anything regarding the code's functionality, it still doesn't allow me to use a file path with spaces, escaped or not.

Comment: FYI, you can also pass in a string to the `FileReader` constructor. Not sure if that would help, but I think I remember using file names with spaces, and it worked fine.

Comment: Well, in URLs, spaces are supposed to be represented with `+` or `%20`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Hassan It worked after i removed the "file://" from the url String. Thanks!

Comment: Recommendation: Please [don't use the `File` class anymore](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks). It's outdated and uninformative. Use the [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class instead.

Comment: File#toURI#toURL if you want to take a File and make a URL reference to it

Answer (score 1):

You can't construct a `File` with a URl string. Just pass a proper *filename* string directly to the constructor of `File,` or indeed the constructor of `FileReader.` There is no issue with spaces in the filename.

> it still doesn't allow me to use a file path with spaces

Yes it does. You are mistaken.

> escaped or not

Filenames do not require escaping. URLS require escaping. But you're just making an unnecessary mess by using the URL class.